# Node JS - AWS SDK - Kinesis - InvalidAction: The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am facing a very weird problem calling kinesis.putRecords() function.
The code works fine when I run it in a standalone file as "node filename". But as soon as I make it as a function to be used in my application like `exports.pushEvents = function pushEvents() {code}` it stops working. The error that I get is "InvalidAction" and is pasted below

I searched online but there is no thread or discussion on this error.
It looks more like an issue with Node JS rather than AWS Kinesis but I may be wrong.

I have also pasted the code that runs perfectly.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sts = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' });
const globalConfig = require("./api-config/config")["global"];
const env = process.env.RAPTOR_ENV || "development";
const config = require("./api-config/config")[env];
console.log(globalConfig.KINESIS_RAPTOR_CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE)
const params = {
   DurationSeconds: 3600, 
   ExternalId: 'raptor',
   RoleArn: globalConfig.KINESIS_RAPTOR_CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE,
   RoleSessionName: 'events'
};

sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
   else {
      console.log("Returned Data: " + JSON.stringify(data,null,3));

      console.log("Now Try Kinesis " );

         //Use the temp credentials returned by STS
         AWS.config.update({
            region: config.awsRegion,
            accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
          });
         // create kinesis service object
         const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({apiVersion: '2013-12-02'});
         console.log("Before sending records")

      let record = {
         Data: '123',
         PartitionKey: '123'
      }
      var records = [];
      records.push(record);
      // upload data to Amazon Kinesis
      kinesis.putRecords({
            Records: records,
            StreamName: globalConfig.KINESIS_STREAM
      }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
               console.error(err); 
            }
            else {
               console.log(data);  
            }
      });   
   } 
});
```

Now if I have put it in a function it doesn't work. Below is the code that doesn't work.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sts = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' });
const { logInfoMessage, logErrorMessage} = require("../utils/log-functions");
const globalConfig = require("./api-config/config")["global"];
const env = process.env.RAPTOR_ENV || "development";
const config = require("./api-config/config")[env];

const params = {
   DurationSeconds: 3600, 
   ExternalId: 'raptor',
   RoleArn: globalConfig.KINESIS_RAPTOR_CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE,
   RoleSessionName: 'events'
};

exports.pushEvents = function pushEvents(records234, operationId) { 
      sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
      if(err) {
            console.log(err);
      }
      else {
         console.log("Returned Data: " + JSON.stringify(data,null,3));
         console.log("Before sending records")

         AWS.config.update({
            region: config.awsRegion,
            accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
      });
      // create kinesis service object
      const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({apiVersion: '2013-12-02'});
      let record = {
         Data: '123',
         PartitionKey: '123'
         }
         var records = [];
         records.push(record);
         // upload data to Amazon Kinesis
         kinesis.putRecords({
            Records: records,
            StreamName: globalConfig.KINESIS_STREAM
         }, function(err, data) {
               if (err) {
               console.error(err);
               }
               else {
               console.log(data);
               }
         });
      } 
      });
};
```

Error that I get

```
{ InvalidAction: The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly.
    at Request.extractError (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/vpras00/Documents/react-12192017/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly.',
  code: 'InvalidAction',
  time: 2017-12-20T21:20:05.752Z,
  requestId: 'd85b51b8-a603-4c97-951d-7c5601ecc0ac',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 22.04675773483902 }
```

Comment: I faced a similar issue. In my case, it was the **region** in the global configuration of AWS causing the issue. In your app code, make sure AWS isn't getting any other global configurations by passing config obj inside the AWS.Kinesis() constructor. And put null for not required configs. See this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58688926/11179586