# InvalidAction: The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito Service Provider to create and list User Pool Clients. I have a locally installed DynamoDB to store the additional data. But I am getting the above error in the callback. I looked a lot for the error context but couldn't fine one.

```
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUserPoolClients(params, function(clientListError, clientListData) {
    console.log(clientListError)
    if(clientListError){
        return res.json({
            status: false,
            message: 'Error Fetching Client Apps',
            data: clientListError
        })
    }
    return res.json({
        status: true,
        message: 'List fetch success',
        data: clientListData
    })
});
```

This is for fetching the user pool client apps. In the same way I am creating the user pool client but I am getting the same error "InvalidAction"

Answer (score 1):

The error thrown was from Dynamodb because I was connected to my local DB which had no tables and data and I was also not passing the credentials generated by the token manager. I removed the local DB URL from the config and then passed the credentials from the token manager and I got the desired result.

Comment: Thank you - we had the same issue and this was the answer after half a day of scratching our heads!

Comment: @kshitij: I didn't get this part "passing the credentials generated by the token manager" what do you mean? what credential do we need to pass?

Comment: @Amir I was using the AWS token manager to generate credentials for the user using its tokens to check the IAM permission for the given DyanamoDB resources.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue, but unable to solve it. Can you guide me on:

> I removed the local DB URL from the config and then passed the credentials from the token manager and I got the desired result.

I am configuring DB this way:

```js
static DB_CONFIG = AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT === 'localhost' ? { endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000', region: 'us-east-1' } : { region: 'us-east-1' };
```

which, in my case is localhost and first object gets passed in.

Comment: I got a worked around. I simply added configurations to the constructor when I created the instance for `CognitoIdentityProviderService`. Something like this:
`new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: null})`.

Leaving it here just in case.

Comment: For me the `endpoint` was the problem. Thanks for this, saved my afternoon.